# PHP not returning false value

Tags: php, function

I have written a piece of code for coupon. whenever I use the function to check if the Coupon Code exists, it returns true and prints the statement. But I can't get the false return and cannot get the statement printed for false case.

```
function db_connect() {
  static $connection;
  if (!isset($connection)) {
    $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
  }
  if ($connection === false) {
    return mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  return $connection;
}

function db_query($query) {
  $connection = db_connect();
  $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
  return $result;
}

function db_error() {
  $connection = db_connect();
  return mysqli_error($connection);
}

function db_select($query) {
  $rows = array();
  $result = db_query($query);
  if ($result === false) {
    return false;
  }
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
  }
  return $rows;
}

function db_rows($query) {
  $result = db_query($query);
  if ($result === false) {
    return false;
  }
  $total_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  return $total_rows;

}

function couponExists($cc) {
  $results = db_rows("SELECT * from ms_coupons where coupon_code='".$cc."'") or die(db_error());
  if ($results > 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

DB table : ms_coupons
coupon_id  coupon_code
1          CODE50
```

check_coupon.php

```
$coupon = $_REQUEST['coupon_code'];
if (!couponExists($coupon)) {
  echo "Does not exist!";
} else {
  echo "Coupon exists!";
}
```

when i supply coupon_code as CODE50 it prints, Coupon exists! but when i supply something different like CODE51 then the pays prints nothing.

Comment: "prints nothing" suggests that there may be an error.  Is there anything in the PHP logs?  When you enable error reporting, is anything displayed on the page?  Maybe place a series of `echo` statements throughout the intended logic to see more specifically where it's deviating from the expected path?

Comment: Did you now that mysql num rows of 0 will equal to false when checkd. So much code ....

Comment: Wouldn't `or die(db_error());` also die when there's 0 results? DB error would also be empty then so nothing will be printed.

Comment: As note to comment from @apokryfos. OP what do you thing will be printed here: `print $var = 0 OR 5;` please remove all `or ` in lines where you bind stuff to an variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with this line in your code:

```
$results = db_rows("SELECT * from ms_coupons where coupon_code='".$cc."'") or die(db_error());
```

`db_rows` function returns number of rows, in your case it can be only two values - **1** or **0**. If db_rows return 0 your script executes the `die(db_error())` part (but there is no mysqli_error).

Remove the `or die(db_error())` part, like this:

```
$results = db_rows("SELECT * from ms_coupons where coupon_code='".$cc."'");
```

If you want to check for mysqli_errors, move it to your `db_query` function.

Comment: You really have sharp eyes